# How to get JSON property based on another property

Tags: javascript, json

Suppose I have a following JSON file:

```
[
  {
    "id" : "1",
    "name" : "Super shirt",
    "snippet": "Item description here",
    "price" : "some price here",
    "category" : "shirt",
    "pic" : "picture1"

  },
  {
    "id" : "2",
    "name" : "Super duper",
    "snippet": "Item description here",
    "price" : "some price here",
    "category" : "shirt",
    "pic" : "picture2"
  }
]
```

and so on. How to get a value of "pic" property based on "id" property of each object?. So how to get a picture of each object if I have an id of that object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for [`Array.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

```
picture = data.find(x => x.id == SOME_ID).pic
```

For older browsers, there's a polyfill on the linked page.

Answer (score 0):

use [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to iterate the array

```
var obj = [
  {
    "id" : "1",
    "name" : "Super shirt",
    "snippet": "Item description here",
    "price" : "some price here",
    "category" : "shirt",
    "pic" : "picture1"


},
  {
    "id" : "2",
    "name" : "Super duper",
    "snippet": "Item description here",
    "price" : "some price here",
    "category" : "shirt",
    "pic" : "picture2"
  }
];

var pic = "";
obj.forEach( function(value){

   if (value.id == "1" )
   {
      pic = value.pic;
   }

} );
alert(pic);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data structure looks like this:

```
var arr= [
  {
    "id" : "1",
    "name" : "Super shirt",
    "snippet": "Item description here",
    "price" : "some price here",
    "category" : "shirt",
    "pic" : "picture1"


},
  {
    "id" : "2",
    "name" : "Super duper",
    "snippet": "Item description here",
    "price" : "some price here",
    "category" : "shirt",
    "pic" : "picture2"
  }
];
```

Then, you can find the pic in your object by searching through the array like this:

```
function findPicById(data, idToLookFor) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        if (data[i].id == idToLookFor) {
            return(data[i].pic);
        }
    }
}
```

for example:

```
var item = findPicByIdId(data, 1);  //return picture1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var data= [{"id" : "1","name" : "Super shirt","snippet": "Item description here","price" : "some price here","category" : "shirt","pic" : "picture1"},
    {"id" : "2","name" : "Super duper","snippet": "Item description here","price" : "some price here","category" : "shirt","pic" : "picture2"}
];
var selected_pic = null;
$.each(data,function(key,value){
    if(value.id == "1"){selected_pic = value.pic;}
});
console.log(selected_pic);
```

Try Above Code: